# Get internet radio url

Tags: internet-radio

I am desperatly looking for the direct url to the internet radio (http://deluxemusic.tv/radio_en/), I have even tried to look in the html code, but I did not find it.
Tanks a lot in advance,
wertzu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:
http://deluxetelevision.com/flash/radio/dlx_music_radio_ims2.swf
Be aware that this is in flash. I am not sure where to find a .pls link.